# How to return result of cast and asInstanceOf in Scala using shapeless

Tags: scala, types, shapeless, type-erasure

I have a function that converts a `Something[Any]` to a `Something[X]` in Scala using typeless:

```scala
import shapeless._
import shapeless.syntax.typeable._

def doCast[T: Typeable](v: Vector[Any]): T = v.cast[T].get
```

Now I want to access the list by index:

```scala
val a = Vector[Any](1,2,3);
println(doCast[Vector[Int]](a)(1))
```

But this throws an exception:

```scala
/path/to/Test.scala:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: shapeless.Typeable[Vector[Any]]
        println(doCast[Vector[Int]](a)(1))
                                       ^
one error found
```

However, if I assign this result to a variable first, it correctly prints `2`:

```scala
val a = Vector[Any](1,2,3);
val c = doCast[Vector[Int]](a)
println(c(1))
```

Similarly, if I cast the result using `asInstanceOf`, it works correctly:

```scala
val a = Vector[Any](1,2,3);
println(doCast[Vector[Int]](a).asInstanceOf[Vector[Int]](1));
```

**Can I create a function that returns the indexable result?**

I tried to do so, but my attempts didn't work:

```scala
def doCast2[T](v: Vector[Any]): T = doCast(v).asInstanceOf[T]
```

gives this error:

```scala
/path/to/Test.scala:10: error: diverging implicit expansion for type shapeless.Typeable[T]
starting with method inrTypeable in object Typeable
    def doCast2[T](v: Vector[Any]): T = doCast(v).asInstanceOf[T]
                                          ^
one error found
```

and

```scala
def doCast2[T](v: Vector[Any]): T = doCast[T](v).asInstanceOf[T]
```

gives this error:

```scala
/path/to/Test.scala:10: error: 
class type required but T found
    def doCast2[T](v: Vector[Any]): T = doCast[T](v).asInstanceOf[T]
                                             ^
one error found
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the actual signature of doCast after desugaring is converted from:

```
def doCast[T: Typeable](v: Vector[Any]): T
```

to

```
def doCast[T](v: Vector[Any])(implicit ev1: Typeable[T]): T
```

So when calling it like this

```
doCast[Vector[Int]](a)(1)
```

you are passing 1 in the position of a Typeable[T].

The easiest solution is to specify the parameter directly:

```
doCast[Vector[Int]](a)(implicitly)(1)
```

Or use the separate val for the vector after doCast